# How to read XML with name/value pair in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

How to read this type of XML in c#? Do you have any sample code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
 <row rownum="1">
    <column colnum="1" name="PROJECT NUMBER">1</column>
    <column colnum="2" name="ROLE">Project Manager</column>
    <column colnum="3" name="FIRSTNAME">Angie</column>
    <column colnum="4" name="LASTNAME">Emanual</column>
</row><row rownum="2">
    <column colnum="1" name="PROJECT NUMBER">2</column>
    <column colnum="2" name="ROLE">Developer</column>
    <column colnum="3" name="FIRSTNAME">Ruha</column>
    <column colnum="4" name="LASTNAME">Rao</column>
</row>
```

Comment: 1) That's not valid XML. You have multiple root nodes. 2) We won't write your code for you. What have you tried so far and where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will read xml fragments

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

            XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create(FILENAME,settings);
            List<object> results = new List<object>();
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "row")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("row");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement row = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    results.Add(new object[] {
                        row.Elements("column").Select(y => new {
                            rowNum = (int)row.Attribute("rownum"),
                            colNum = (int)y.Attribute("colnum"),
                            colName = (string)y.Attribute("name"),
                            value = (string)y
                        }).FirstOrDefault()
                    });

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```